# Selecting sort buttons on table

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have a table that I need to select the sort ascending and descending buttons. The html looks like this

```
<table id="results" class="list-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="header-row ">
<th>
<th id="field_app_job_title" class="app_job_title ">
<th id="field_app_full_name" class="app_full_name ">
<th id="field_app_individual_workflow_states"   class="v0_workflow_state_definition_id_sort ">
<th id="field_app_workflow_state_entrance_reason"  class="v0_workflow_state_entrance_reason_sort ">
<span class="controls">
<span class="move_left"></span>
<span class="move_right" style="display: none;"></span>
<span class="sort_asc"></span>
<span class="sort_desc"></span>
<span class="remove"></span>
</span>
Workflow State Entrance Reason
</th>
<th class="action-menu"></th>
</tr>
```

I have tried the following:

```
within_table  'results' do
  find('Workflow State Entrance Reason').click_link('sort_asc')
end
```

or

```
within_table  'results' do
  find('v0_workflow_state_entrance_reason_sort').click_link('sort_asc')
end
```

and even this, but none has located the element so far.

```
within_table  'results' do
  ('input[id^="field_app_workflow_state_entrance_reason"]').click_link('sort_asc')
end
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyones input and sorry for my late response. Your answers led me down the correct path and I was able to resolve this. One problem was I didn't realize was that the sort elements did not appear until the mouse was hovering over the column.

```
within_table 'results' do
  find('#field_app_workflow_state_entrance_reason', text: 'Workflow State Entrance Reason').hover
end
```

This then gave a new error where I was getting this error

> Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed: Firing a click at
>   co-ordinates [719.5, 438] failed. Poltergeist detected another element
>   with CSS selector 'html body#job_applications.search div#container
>   section#main div#main-content section.details div.subpage
>   section#search_results table#results.list-table tbody tr.header-row
>   th#field_app_workflow_state_entrance_reason.v0_workflow_state_entrance_reason_sort span.controls' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you
>   are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping
>   elements, try using node.trigger('click').

A bit of research on the node.trigger and I was able to click the element like this without getting the error.

```
within_table 'results' do
  find('.v0_workflow_state_entrance_reason_sort span.controls .sort_asc').trigger("click")
end
```

I'm not sure if this is a great idea or not, but it seems to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS selector to [find](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#finding) the element and then click on it. Use something like this:

```
find(".sort_asc").click
```

You should also review your HTML code which seems to be invalid (you have nasted `th` selectors).

Comment: Unfortunately there are multiple of these sort_asc across each column. I have 6 or 7 columns and this is across the top of each. So trying to see how to I can select just the ones from the column titled Workflow State Entrance Reason.  Thanks for the heads up on the HTML code. I am in QA and don't write that part.

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid, but if you have those `span` elements in every `th` column, then you can use `find(".class-of-th .sort_asc").click` or even `find("...", text: "Workflow...").click`

Answer (score 0):

Given your html (that hopefully gets fixed) the following should click what you're trying to click

```
within_table 'results' do
  find('.v0_workflow_state_entrance_reason_sort .sort_asc').click
end
```

The reasons your attempts didn't work are below

```
within_table  'results' do
  # find with no selector type specified takes a CSS selector
  # not random text and there is no link (<a> element in your html)
  find('Workflow State Entrance Reason').click_link('sort_asc')        
end

within_table  'results' do
  # v0_workflow... is not the correct CSS selector (unless that is the tag_name of the element you're looking for) and there is no link in your html
  find('v0_workflow_state_entrance_reason_sort').click_link('sort_asc')
end

within_table  'results' do
  #there is no link in your html
  find('input[id^="field_app_workflow_state_entrance_reason"]').click_link('sort_asc')
end
```